# How can I draw a rectangle or sprite onto another sprite in xna?

Tags: sprite, xna-4.0, collision

I'm working on a 2d game in xna. Basically I want to draw a rectangle or sprite on another sprite with collision. I can detect the collision and everything, but I don't know how I can draw on the sprite. I'm drawing the rectangle on the sprite, but it's drawing behind the sprite which makes the rectangle invisible. Is there way I can accomplish this?

Comment: it is drawing behind the sprite because in your draw method you are drawing it first. Instead draw it second. ( after your sprite is drawn)

Comment: I'm drawing the way you told. Also these are two different sprite batches, so does it effect?

Comment: I can't show since I have multiple classes, basically they are nested sprite batches.

Comment: Show us the code that corresponds with your problem and comment out the rest.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I just accessed the spritebatch instance from main and calling it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of layer ordering:

```
    public enum TextureName : byte
    {
        Black,
        Yellow
    }
    private GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    public struct Sprite
    {
        public Vector2 Position;
        public Texture2D Texture;
        public Sprite(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
        {
            Position = position;
            Texture = texture;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<TextureName, Sprite> Sprites { get; private set; }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Sprites = new Dictionary<TextureName, Sprite>();
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2 - 64, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2 - 64);
        Sprites.Add(TextureName.Black, new Sprite(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"black_sprite"), position));
        Sprites.Add(TextureName.Yellow, new Sprite(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"yellow_sprite"), position + new Vector2(32, 32)));
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Sprites[TextureName.Black].Texture, Sprites[TextureName.Black].Position, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);// -> will be drawn first
        spriteBatch.Draw(Sprites[TextureName.Yellow].Texture, Sprites[TextureName.Yellow].Position, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);// -> will be drawn second
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

So the black sprite will be behind.
[image: First example]

You can reorder your Sprites with ease using a SpriteSortMode of the SpriteBatch.Begin() method and setting layer depth for SpriteBatch.Draw() method as shown below.

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Sprites[TextureName.Black].Texture, Sprites[TextureName.Black].Position, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f/* layer depth*/);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Sprites[TextureName.Yellow].Texture, Sprites[TextureName.Yellow].Position, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f/* layer depth*/);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

The output will be:
[image]

If you are using different sprite batches from other classes. The first example will work fine. Just take care about placing your "YourClass.Draw()" in right order into the main game draw method.

Be aware of using second example. It works much slower than first.